# Filtrar datos de un reporte en Jasperreports (Ireport) netbeans sql

Tags: sql, netbeans, jsp, jasper-reports, ireport

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para lo cual tengo varios reportes; ya he logrado visualizarlos todos completos por medio de un *jsp*; sin embargo, quiero darle al usuario la opción de filtrar datos. Por ejemplo, en mi reporte de ventas quiero filtrar mis datos por medio del `idventa` utilizando una caja de texto en un *jsp* y que solo me muestre los datos de ese id y, por lo tanto, si el usuario no escribe nada en la caja de texto que no filtre y muestre el reporte completo...

Hasta el momento, en mi reporte, he creado un parámetro con la opción que tiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he declarado como un `integer`, puesto que el campo que tengo en mi base de datos está en `Integer`, así que me imagino debería funcionar así... ahora en mi query tengo este código:

```
 SELECT
 Receta."IDReceta" AS Receta_IDReceta,
 Receta."IDPersonal" AS Receta_IDPersonal,
 Receta."Fecha_Receta" AS Receta_Fecha_Receta,
 Venta."IDVenta" AS Venta_IDVenta,
 Venta."IDReceta" AS Venta_IDReceta,
 Detalle_Receta."IDReceta" AS Detalle_Receta_IDReceta,
 Detalle_Receta."Nummed" AS Detalle_Receta_Nummed,
 Detalle_Receta."IDMedicamento" AS Detalle_Receta_IDMedicamento,
 Detalle_Receta."Cantidad" AS Detalle_Receta_Cantidad,
 Detalle_Receta."Indicaciones" AS Detalle_Receta_Indicaciones,
 Kardex."IDKardex" AS Kardex_IDKardex,
 Kardex."IDMedicamento" AS Kardex_IDMedicamento,
 Kardex."IDVentas" AS Kardex_IDVentas,
 Kardex."TipoMovimiento" AS Kardex_TipoMovimiento,
 Kardex."Cantidad" AS Kardex_Cantidad,
 Medicamento."IDMedicamento" AS Medicamento_IDMedicamento,
 Medicamento."Nombre" AS Medicamento_Nombre,
 Medicamento."Descripcion" AS Medicamento_Descripcion,
 Medicamento."ComponenteActivo" AS Medicamento_ComponenteActivo,
 Medicamento."Presentacion" AS Medicamento_Presentacion,
 Medicamento."Existencia" AS Medicamento_Existencia,
 Medicamento."UnidadMedida" AS Medicamento_UnidadMedida,
 Medicamento."PrecioUnitario" AS Medicamento_PrecioUnitario
 FROM
 "dbo"."Receta" Receta INNER JOIN "dbo"."Venta" Venta ON Receta."IDReceta" = Venta."IDReceta"
 INNER JOIN "dbo"."Detalle_Receta" Detalle_Receta ON Receta."IDReceta" = Detalle_Receta."IDReceta"
 INNER JOIN "dbo"."Kardex" Kardex ON Venta."IDVenta" = Kardex."IDVentas"
 INNER JOIN "dbo"."Medicamento" Medicamento ON Kardex."IDMedicamento" = Medicamento."IDMedicamento"

 WHERE Kardex."IDVentas" = $P{idventa}
```

Donde está el `WHERE Kardex."IDVentas" = $P{idventa}` es donde debería hacer mi filtro al id de ventas que tiene kardex; o al menos eso me propongo. Sin embargo no quiere hacer el filtro cuando hago la *preview* del reporte. Por favor ayuda, soy algo novato en esto de *SQL* y también no tengo mucha experiencia. No sé si estoy haciendo bien la referencia. ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Tu problema es que no funciona solo cuando lo dejas en blanco, o no funciona en ningún caso?

Comment: Hola, si.. mi problema es que por ejemplo creo mi parametro como lo mostré arriba, al momento de ir a la ventana de preview en netbeans me pregunta por el parametro, diciendome que agrege un valor para filtrar, por ejemplo le pongo 1 y me tendria que filtrar todo lo que tenga 1 en el id de ventas de mi base y crear el reporte, y le doy en ok, luego me sale el reporte pero no me filtró nada, me muestra todos los datos

Comment: A nivel de `jasper` el código luce bien. ¿has intentado ejecutar el query en directamente sobre tu base de datos y allí si funciona correctamente el filtro?

Comment: Si lo he hecho sin embargo no quiere filtrar

Comment: Si el query no filtra correctamente al ejecutarlo directamente contra la base de datos, el problema no está en Jasper, el problema está en el Query, por lo que Jasper resulta irrelevante. Al corregir el query, funcionará correctamente en Jasper.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer como crear un [mcve]. Un saludo.